# Is it possible to convert std_msgs/Int8 to a binary number?

Tags: ros, python2.7, binary

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to convert a std_msgs/Int8 messsage that I receive from a topic to a binary number in python.

The way I am currently doing it is by doing this dirty hack.

```
bin(int(str(data)))
```

but isn't there any nice way to do this? I mean this is python so something clever should be there...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246894/is-it-possible-to-convert-std_msgs/int8-to-a-binary-number?/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure why you're converting to a string and then back to an int.

If you have an Int8, you should be able to call `bin()` on the data member directly:

```
# Import the Int8 message definition
from std_msgs.msg import Int8

# create an Int8 message and assign 32 to it
num = Int8()
num.data = 32

# call bin() on our Int8 data and print the result
print bin(num.data)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1